# .htaccess: Replace part of url for a domain

Tags: .htaccess

I have this url
www.mydomain.com/aftomelanomenes-sfragides/eos-7-grammes/197430-092399532491-sfragida-trodat-printy-4915-aytomelanomeni-mple-detail

and I would like to replace it with this
www.mydomain.com/aftomelanomenes-sfragides/eos-7-grammes/197430-092399532491-sfragida-trodat-printy-4915-aftomelanomeni-mple-detail

i tried this code to htaccess

RewriteRule ^-aftomelanomeni-?$ -aytomelanomeni-$1 [NC,L]

But it doesn't work

Comment: You can specify full urls:
**Redirect /aftomelanomenes-sfragides/eos-7-grammes/197430-092399532491-sfragida-trodat-printy-4915-aytomelanomeni-mple-detail  /aftomelanomenes-sfragides/eos-7-grammes/197430-092399532491-sfragida-trodat-printy-4915-aftomelanomeni-mple-detail**

Comment: I have many urls like this...more than 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)-aytomelanomeni-(.+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1-aftomelanomeni-$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you it works
When clicked the url changes

it is not possible to have the url displaying correctly atthe list before clicking the wrong ur?

Comment: Ok, understood. If you have those urls in database - you should replace them in database and no need htaccess redirect

Comment: My problem is that my client uses a software to update products from his warehouse and this aliases are changed by default and I cannot change my client's software because it is an exe file and the software house doesn't change it.

Comment: Ok, then only solution is redirection

Comment: Thank you for your time I really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept answer if it was helpful

Comment: I am new to this. I was just reading posts. This is the first time I have posted.